# What corporation tax am I required to pay as an independent contractor?

Tags: taxes, canada, corporation, canada-revenue-agency

Refer to this link [at Canada Revenue Agency](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/crprtns/rts-eng.html).

I am unsure that for an Ontario resident who opens up a corporation, what corporation tax would I pay? Let's say I charge 60$/hr + 13% HST to my client.  What do I owe in corporation tax to the CRA? 15% federal + (4.5 or 11.5%) for Ontario?  What is the difference between the low rate and high rate?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the provincial/territorial low and high corporate income tax rates is clear if you read through the page you linked:

> **Lower rate**
>
> *The lower rate applies to the income eligible for the federal **small
>   business deduction**.* One component of the small business deduction is
>   the business limit. Some provinces or territories choose to use the
>   federal business limit. Others establish their own business limit.
>
> **Higher rate**
>
> The higher rate applies to *all other income.*    *[emphasis mine]*

Essentially, you pay the lower rate **only if your income qualifies for the federal small business deduction (SBD).**

If you then followed the [small business deduction](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/t4012/t4012-06-e.html) link in the same page, you'd find the SBD page describing "active business income" from a business carried on in Canada as qualifying for the small business deduction.  If your corporation is an investment vehicle realizing passive investment income, generally that *isn't* considered "active business income."

Determining if *your* business qualifies for the SBD isn't trivial — it depends on the nature of your business and the kind and amount of income it generates.  Talk to a qualified corporate tax accountant.

If you're looking at doing IT contracting, also pay close attention to the definition of "personal services business", which wouldn't qualify for the SBD.  Your accountant should be able to advise you how best to conduct your business in order to qualify for the SBD.  Don't have a good accountant?  Get one.  I wouldn't operate as an incorporated IT contractor without one.

I'll also note that the federal rate you would pay would also differ based on whether or not you qualified for the SBD.  (15% if you didn't qualify, vs. 11% if you qualify.)

The combined corporate income tax rate for a Canadian-controlled private corporation in Ontario that does qualify for the small business deduction would be 11% + 4.5% = 15.5% (in 2013).

Additional reading:

- [The Blunt Bean Counter - Is Your Corporation a Personal Service Business?](http://www.thebluntbeancounter.com/2012/01/is-your-corporation-personal-service.html)
- [Personal Services Business Rules](http://madanca.com/blog/personal-services-business-rules-it-contractors-and-consultants-taxes/) and [How to Avoid the Personal Services Business Rules](http://madanca.com/blog/how-to-avoid-the-personal-services-business-rules-it-contractors-and-independent-consultants/)

Comment: Thanks a lot and I will be more careful when posting. So as per law, I charge client 13% and pay CRA 15.5%? I was of the wrong impression that at least i would break even :)

Comment: @Kaushik **No.**  The 13% HST you charge is *not* related to the corporate income tax rates addressed in my answer. (I assumed you understood HST already.) For the 13% HST you collect on revenues, you must remit a portion to the CRA (and how much, exactly, is a subject for a completely different question.) On top of HST, your corporation must also pay corporate income tax (such as at rates described in the answer above) on the net income (profit) of the corporation.  i.e. HST & corp income tax are **two** different taxes and your corporation will pay **both** (assuming it is profitable).

Comment: I'll stress again that **you should engage the services of a corporate tax accountant**.  Don't try to do this yourself, at least not at first.